# Function gets called multiple times

Tags: c++, sfml, game-development

So, inside the game loop function that tracks user input is called multiple times. I guess this happens because game loop goes like 40 iterations each second and if I hold down the key for a 0.5 second, function gets called 20 times. I tried to handle this with sfml events too but it didn't work `window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false)`. How can I solve this?

```
//this gets called 20-30times
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
{
    leftPlayerPoints++;
}
```

Comment: Don't use counters, but use boolean *flags*? When a key is first pressed set a flag, when it's release clear the flag. Check flag in main game event loop.

Comment: This is exactly what `isKeyPressed` is for. If you're interested in the button being pressed check for `KeyPressed` and `KeyReleased` events.

Comment: It's described in the basic [handle events](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-events.php) tutorial on their webpage btw.

Comment: @Some-Programmer-dude, doesn't metter, boolean will be true during ~40 iteration until KeyReleased event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *two* boolean flags: One for checking if the key is pressed or not, and one that is used to check if the action have happened yet.

In short something like

```
if (key_is_pressed)
{
    if (!action_have_happened)
    {
        // Perform action...
        action_have_happened = true;
    }
    // Else: Action have already happened this key-press, don't do it again
}
```

When the key is released reset both flags (to `false`).

Comment: That works but It would be better to use the built-in SFML event ```sf::Event::KeyPressed``` instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @LucsCharbonnier, what do you mean ? ```sf::Event::KeyPressed``` did not help. Could you explain please?

Answer (score 1):

That's what exactly `IsKeyPressed` is suppose to do , you have to use bitmasking and make it toggle state instead of continuing pressing.

Below is code from *Win32API* (C++). I know *SFML* has different events than *Win32API* but Masking should work in *SFML* also.

```
BOOL IsKeyToggled(CONST INT key)
{
    SHORT key_state = GetAsyncKeyState(key);
    BOOL is_toggled = key_state & 0x1;
    return is_toggled;
}
```

The main point here is `key_state & 0x1;` bit masking with `0x1`